# Load iframe src using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to load the iframe src for the parent iframe. But its not working for me.

```
  var cur_iframeid = frameElement.id;
  alert(cur_iframeid);//Parent iframe id 
  var value = "activity.aspx?id=Y&cust_id=" + cust_id + "&role_id=" + role +";
  alert(value);
  cur_iframeid.src = value;//Its not working.
```

Comment: Is the `+"` at the end of `var value` line a typo? If not, then you have a syntax error which could be the problem.

Comment: No i assign only activity.aspx. But its not working.

Comment: Please read my comment again. There is a syntax error and the code should read `var value = "activity.aspx?id=Y&cust_id=" + cust_id + "&role_id=" + role;`

Answer (score 2):

seems you are tring to set the source on the frameelement id..not the frame elements...
try either:

```
frameElement.src = value
```

or

```
document.getElementById(cur_iframeid).src = value
```

Comment: At least then give me a one up on my answer then? :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the source of the frame id.
I think you need to set the source of the frame:

```
frameElement.src = value
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the exact result.